# Snort Content first 3 bytes the same then create an alert

Tags: ids, snort

I was wondering if you could add into a snort rule the ability to only alert if the first 3 bytes match. I think I need to edit the content in my current rule `content:"|37 e1 a4|";` I can add the full rule if that can help.